# Intermittent CORS policy issue with ABP (AspNet Boilerplate) API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

ASP.NET Zero (.Net Core v2 + Angular v5)

AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll breaking sometimes, after serving few requests it start generating cross domain issue other times it works perfectly.

Following is the error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:22743/AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> GET http://localhost:22743/AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll net::ERR_FAILED

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The ASP.NET Zero have configured CORS Origins allowed-list properly already, just ensure that you put the right value on the `App:CorsOrigins` setting in `appsettings.json` file.

```
{
  ...
  "App": {    
    "ServerRootAddress": "http://localhost:22743/",
    "ClientRootAddress": "http://localhost:4200/",
    "CorsOrigins": "http://localhost:4200",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

2. Sometimes, the error message is **misleading**. It show this error because some errors occur on server side. Just investigate the log file or debug and fix it, then this message will gone.

Comment: Thanks! I will check and get back to you.

Comment: #2 worked for me.. it was some issue related to Redis cahce timeout, I disabled its initialization piece in debug mode.. now seems working fine. Thanks!

Comment: @ANKIT if this has solved your problem, could you consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) please?

Comment: @ANKIT could you please tell me how you disable it in debug mode as I have the same issue?

Comment: It was number 2 issue for me, this was really misleading and spent hours on it

Answer (score 0):

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Origins": [
    "http://localhost:4200",
  ]
}
```

Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowedOrigins",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                            .WithOrigins(Configuration.GetSection("Origins").GetChildren().Select(c => c.Value)
                                .ToArray())
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });
        }
```